# How can I invoke GWT 2.6.1 from GWT 1.5.3

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have an old project developed using GWT 1.5.3, which I run using "com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler" or by selecting the module.gwt.xml and say "Run as Hosted Mode".
Now I have a requirement to create a new module under the same project using GWT 2.6.1, to run this I need to use "com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler". I created a separate module and it works fine when it is ran alone.

Now I have to locally run the GWT 1.5 app from which I need to invoke the GWT 2.6 module.

Please suggest me how do I achieve this?

Note : Both of these 2 modules have separate module.gwt.xml and .html files

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the only way I see would be a second hostpage. Then you could create a link (anchor) from the old application to the new one.

But, I think the better solution would be to upgrade the old project to GWT (2.7 is the current version)

Comment: But the new module (GWT 2.6) is not compiled when I run my old module in hosted mode. so I doubt the anchor will help me anyway.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If it have to be the same project, you will need to update it to the same version. 1.5 is ancient (I think IE7 was the newest "browser", that days)